# Conditional Counting on Pandas Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-science

I've a IPL dataset that looks like below:

```
df.head(10):        

                  toss_winner                       winner
0    Royal Challengers Bangalore          Sunrisers Hyderabad
1         Rising Pune Supergiant       Rising Pune Supergiant
2          Kolkata Knight Riders        Kolkata Knight Riders
3                Kings XI Punjab              Kings XI Punjab
4    Royal Challengers Bangalore  Royal Challengers Bangalore
5          Sunrisers Hyderabad          Sunrisers Hyderabad
6               Mumbai Indians               Mumbai Indians
7  Royal Challengers Bangalore              Kings XI Punjab
8       Rising Pune Supergiant             Delhi Daredevils
9               Mumbai Indians               Mumbai Indians
```

I want to group my data based on number of counts each team win the toss, and number of times they win the match after winning the toss.

For ex, the desired output is:

```
team                    total_toss_win                     win_on_toss_win
Royal Challengers Bangalore   3                                     1
Rising Pune Supergiant        2                                     1 
Kolkata Knight Riders         1                                     1
Kings XI Punjab               1                                     1  (although 2 wins, but lost the toss on second win)
and so on....
```

I've tried variant of groupby and aggregation, but nothing seems to be working

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind showing us your attempts?

Answer (score 0):

try `melt` then `groupby` with `unstack`

```
s = pd.melt(df).groupby('value')['variable'].value_counts().unstack('variable')\
                .fillna(0)

print(s)

variable                     toss_winner  winner
value                                           
Delhi Daredevils                     0.0     1.0
Kings XI Punjab                      1.0     2.0
Kolkata Knight Riders                1.0     1.0
Mumbai Indians                       2.0     2.0
Rising Pune Supergiant               2.0     1.0
Royal Challengers Bangalore          3.0     1.0
Sunrisers Hyderabad                  1.0     2.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I was doing something same, was just missing melt( ).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to understand each step:

```
# number of counts each team win the toss
a = df.groupby("toss_winner").size()

# number of times they win the match after winning the toss
b = df.query("toss_winner == winner").groupby(["toss_winner"]).size()

# output
f = pd.concat([a, b], axis=1).reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'total_toss_win', 1: 'win_on_toss_win'})

print(f)

                   toss_winner  total_toss_win  win_on_toss_win
0              Kings XI Punjab               1                1
1        Kolkata Knight Riders               1                1
2               Mumbai Indians               2                2
3       Rising Pune Supergiant               2                1
4  Royal Challengers Bangalore               3                1
5          Sunrisers Hyderabad               1                1
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, it's a very simple and efficient solution